# Can I insert a hyperlink to my checkbox in WPF?

Tags: wpf, checkbox, hyperlink

I'm writing a project in WPF.
I have checkboxes and I want part of the text to be a hyperlink.
Is it possible and if so how?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is really hard to understand what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

To have a link, we normally use the `Hyperlink` element. However to have just some words rendered as `Hyperlink` inside the `Content` of a CheckBox, you need to use another wrapper element which allows mixed content of text and link. I've found 2 such wrappers, the first is `TextBlock` and the second is `Span`, both work OK:

```
<CheckBox>
  <CheckBox.Content>
    <TextBlock>
      Visit <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://stackoverflow.com">StackOverFlow
            </Hyperlink> to learn more.
    </TextBlock>
  </CheckBox.Content>
</CheckBox>
```

or

```
<CheckBox>
  <CheckBox.Content>
    <Span>
      Visit <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://stackoverflow.com">StackOverFlow
            </Hyperlink> to learn more.
    </Span>
  </CheckBox.Content>
</CheckBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
     <CheckBox>
        <CheckBox.Content>
            <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://www.google.co.in">
                Click here
            </Hyperlink>
        </CheckBox.Content>
    </CheckBox>
```